# Play a list of media (video/audio) items on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, video-player

I'm developing an iPhone App and I need to implement a player to play a list of media (video/audio) items.

Following is a screenshot of player I have captured from an another iPhone app, I found many apps playing video/audio using a player has similar UI like this.

Can this player (including UI) can be implement by official API? Or just implement manually?

How can I implement a same player like this?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

To Play audio follow [**this blog**](http://mobileorchard.com/easy-audio-playback-with-avaudioplayer/)

And to play video, either you can use CustomMovieplayer or go with UIWebView with embedded html.

Movie Player sample code from [**here**](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/mediaplayer-framework_mpmovieplayercontroller_ios4/)

To play video as embedded html in UIWebView, check this..
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7551375/790794

As per the file type, you can modify the source type.

Comment: I just want to implemnet a same player as the screenshot I posted

Comment: For that, you have to use a custom movie player, a customized player from MPMoviePlayer.

Comment: I have posted the link for MPMoviePlayer from which you can create your own movie player.